# CoreData bindings not persisting one entity attribute

Tags: cocoa, core-data, persistence, cocoa-bindings

I have a simple form with 3 text boxes and one popup button on it. These fields are bound to a coredata entity (Account) with one relationship to a second entity (AccountType). The popup button list is populated from the AccountType entity and is bound to the Account.type relationship. I also have a save button which performs a save of the current entity from the forms controller code...

```
NSError *error;   
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save: &error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
}
```

Everything persists to my xml backing store just fine except for the contents of one of my text boxes, call it textbox3. textbox1, textbox2 and the relationship save just fine to the XML file, but nothing for textbox3, nor are there any errors on the save.

If I remove textbox3, everything saves just fine except textbox2. If I instead copy textbox3 onto the form so there are 2 bindings for the same entity attribute, textbox1, textbox2, textbox3 and the relationship persist just fine.

Has anyone seen this behavior before with coredata?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I figured this out somewhat, it seems that the attribute is not being saved because I wasn't tabbing away from the textfield on setting the value. If I tab away from the textfield after entering a value, the attribute is set with the new value.

Comment: So it seems the bound attribute value is not updated until you move away from the textfield, is it possible to change that behavior to update the attribute value as soon at the textfield value has changed?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on the design of your app.  The AppKit UI elements implement `NSEditor` so you can use `-commitEditing`.  I've also seen people shift the `firstResponder` to force the field editor to commit, although I would consider this a hack.